# ¿Cómo detectar botones de hardware (dispositivo físico) en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Quiero bloquear el botón de encendido / bloqueo, necesito poder controlar ese botón para evitar que mi aplicación se bloquee.

Use este paquete `https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons`, hice pruebas en 2 marcas de teléfonos celulares y solo funciona en Samsung, la otra marca es Huawei y no funciona.

Dispositivo Huawei Android 8.1.0,
2do dispositivo Huawei Android 6.0 y
3er dispositivo Samsung Android 8.0.0 - en este funciona

```
    StreamSubscription<HardwareButtons.LockButtonEvent> _lockButtonSubscription;

    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _lockButtonSubscription = HardwareButtons.lockButtonEvents.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        _latestHardwareButtonEvent = 'LOCK_BUTTON';
      });
    });
    }
      @override
      void dispose() {
      super.dispose();
      _lockButtonSubscription?.cancel();
      }
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('CooPie'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Mostrar Evento: $_latestHardwareButtonEvent\n'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Agradecería si tiene alguna sugerencia, gracias.

Comment: Acá los comentarios "absténganse de comentar" no van, por favor. Sólo amor y paz. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Flutter incluye un widget por defecto llamado RawKeyboardListener, puedes intentar capturarlo de esa forma. El problema que veo es que el botón de encendido esta controlado a nivel de S.O así que el S.O automáticamente bloquea tu teléfono al presionarlo. De todos modos puedes intentar:

```
RawKeyboardListener(
                focusNode: New FocusNode(),
                onKey: (key) {
                 Aqui puedes capturar los datos del boton.
                  }
                })
```